# How would a quark star maintain degeneracy near the surface?

Tags: particle-physics, stars, quarks, neutron-stars, quark-gluon-plasma

I'm still not exactly understanding how a quark star could possibly exist for more than a fraction of a second. Neutron stars are already hypothesized to have degenerate quark matter at their cores, and I'd assume that that matter couldn't extend very far up through a quark star, since the pressure closer to the surface wouldn't be able to maintain quark degeneracy. So I'd think that any "quark star" would really just be a neutron star with a large core - but according to [this Harvard paper](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2013IAUS..291...61W), quark stars "can be bare (pure quark stars) or enveloped in thin nuclear crusts (0.00001 Earth masses)". How would it get to the point where it's almost all degenerate quark matter if there were far different pressures at the center than near the surface?

Comment: I do not know the topic, but I would think the fact that the color force  does not allow free quarks is an extra force entering the argument , not just gravitational pressure.